# C++ library to discover sql database schema for multiple vendors?

Tags: c++, sql, database, schema

Just wondering if anyone knows of a C++ library that provides a single interface for querying database schema (tables, fields, field types), and for a variety of vendors?  I know DTL does this to some degree, although I haven't dug into the details of how it does it, or if it makes that info available external to itself.

*ODBC is probably fine, and I've already considered it, but I'd just like to see if there are other libraries that might encompass ODBC, native drivers (to get access to info that ODBC may not provide?), obscure databases that may not provide ODBC drivers, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done with [ODBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Database_Connectivity).

Comment: Lol, I should have known.  Now I just look silly.  I considered the ODBC schema functions, but I didn't know if there would be significant differences in the way vendors implement them (say, for various levels of ODBC compliance), or in the way the information is shaped when it's handed to the client, etc.  I wanted something that would deal w/ differences like that.  Any idea if details like that would vary from vendor to vendor?